# Why is FileSystemRights enum incomplete?

Tags: c#

**Question:** Is there a design reason why the [FileSystemRights Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights.aspx) only includes some, but not all, file system rights? If so, where can I find an explanation and options on how to handle any additional file system rights not included in the enum that might be encountered when checking the access rights for a file\folder.

**Details:** When getting FileSystemRights for a file\folder using C#, sometimes it will return a value that is not included in [FileSystemRights Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights.aspx).

Example, the following code will fail when it returns the access right value '268435456'  when calling FileSystemAccessRule.FileSystemRights because 268435456 is not currently included in FileSystemRights Enum.

```
        bool access;
        string NtAccountName = @"myDomain\myUserOrGroup";
        NtAccountName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
        DirectorySecurity acl = di.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);
        AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = acl.GetAccessRules(true,true, typeof(NTAccount));
        var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());


        foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
        {

            bool isInGoup = principal.IsInRole(rule.IdentityReference.Value);
            FileSystemAccessRule fsAccessRule = rule as FileSystemAccessRule;
            if (fsAccessRule == null)
                continue;

            if (isInGoup)
            {

                if ((fsAccessRule.FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.ListDirectory) > 0)
                {
                    access = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    access = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is unlikely to find actual reason, answer linked by @Winks gives you information on how to deal with it.

Comment: Basically everything that is in `FileSystemRights` corresponds properly to one of the _**standard** access mask_ values for files/folders. The generic access mask values have simply been left out. So right there's your answer: they only mapped the standard access mask values ... so technically it's not incomplete, I reckon it was a very conscious decision.